# Mystery ajax request occurring somehow

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete, requirejs

Whenever I type in the autocomplete field an ajax request is sent and there is no code I've written to do this. Checking the console I see it's a 400 GET request to the controller that loaded this view with param (json) appended to the url. I'm absolutely stumped.

```
<head>
<script data-main="<?=base_url()?>public/requirejs/main.js" src="<?=base_url()?>public/requirejs/require-jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    requirejs(['a_mod'],
        function(a_mod) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var param = [];
                param = $('#elem').attr('value');
                a_mod.foo(param, "#someElem");
            });
        });
<script>
```

**main.js**

```
require(["jquery",
         "jquery-ui"],
         function() {

         }
);
```

The autocomplete function

```
'foo' : function(param, elementAutocomplete, elementTags) {
        console.log("init ac");
        $(elementAutocomplete).autocomplete({
            source: param,
            minLength: 1,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                //
            }

        }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            return $("<li></li>")
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                .append( '<a>' + item.label  + '</a>' )
                .appendTo(ul);
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `source` attribute for the autocompleter is a string:

```
param = $('#elem').attr('value');
```

And a [string `source` means](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete) that it is a URL:

> Autocomplete can be customized to work with various data sources, by just specifying the source option. A data source can be:
>
> - an Array with local data
> - a String, specifying a URL
> - a Callback

Saying `var param = [];` just means that `param` is initialized as an empty array, it doesn't mean that `param` will always be an array. You need to fix your `param` value to be an array.